# Leaflet 'dragend' event handler lost after dragging parent element

Tags: javascript, leaflet

'mouseup' and 'dragend' evenst are fired when you stop dragging a map but leaflets 'dragend' event stops firing after the parent element has been dragged

```
<div class='dragBox'>
    <div class='header'>Title</div>
    <div class='mapContainer'>
        <div class='leaflet-container'>...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dragging the 'dragBox' is started by a 'mousedown' handler attached to 'header' which removes 'mousedown' from 'header' and installs 'mousemove' and 'mouseup' on document.body

'mouseup' on document.body removes 'mousemove' and 'mouseup' handlers from document.body and reinstalles 'mousdown' on 'header'

All events are installed by el.addEventListener(eventName, handler) and removed by el.removeEventListener(eventName, handler)

I wonder why my event-handling are affecting the leaflet handlers and if there is a way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating from 1.6.0 to 1.7.1 solved the problem